# CAPL script to update engine rpm on display ECU

Tags: can-bus, capl, canalyzer

I have written code in CAPL script to update engine speed.

```
variable
{
  message EEC1_01 mymsg;
  msTimer t_mymsg;
}
on start
{ 
  myMsg.byte(3)=0x60;
  myMsg.byte(4)=0x22;
  setTimerCyclic(mymsg,50);
}
on timer t_mymsg
{
  output (myMsg);
}
```

I am able to see that frame in being transmitted over CAN bus after each 50 sec but that EngineRPM value is not being updated on connected display.

And when I am sending the same frame from IG block value is being updated on Display.

Comment: The timer is executed exactly once. 50 milliseconds after measurement start. Is that what you want?

Comment: Please provide screen shots of the IG block, trace window, the Display and how you are updating the display values.